# Duvida na galeria de imagens

Tags: html, css

Estou querendo fazer esse tipo de efeito na minha galeria de imagem, quando passar o mouse por cima de alguma imagem, ela simplesmente destaca a imagem e as outras escurecem. Segue o modelo: [Modelo](http://themeforest.net/item/elegantcart-a-premium-responsive-opencart-theme/full_screen_preview/2574191). Se possível queria via CSS.

Comment: Se sua duvida é como fazer via CSS, da pra fazer usando o seletor :hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só por CSS não dá porque a opacidade se aplica a todos os elementos pertencentes ao carrossel, então tem que ser por JS mesmo.

Para o exemplo no link, usando jQuery:

```
$('.products_container .product_holder').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).siblings().fadeTo("fast", 0.6);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings().fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }
);
```

Explicando:

- [`$(this).siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) seleciona todos os elementos com a(s) mesma(s) classe(s) no mesmo nível de profundidade de *tags*;
- [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) é o evento de passar o cursor por cima do elemento, e pede dois *callbacks*: um de entrada na `div` e um de saída;
- [`.fadeTo()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) cria o efeito de opacidade (no caso, 0.6 para entrada e 1 para saída);

[Aqui tem um exemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/1homazpx/).